# No se puede convertir de 'int' a 'string' en C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Estoy desarrollando mi aplicativo web en ASP.NET y por cuestiones de cambio del negocio se tuvo que cambiar el tipo de dato del atributo **serviceId** de string a int

```
var services = ServicesModel.GetServices(Session["area"]?.ToString(), (bool) Session["empl"]).ServicesList;
            var serviceId = ticket.ServiceId;
            var serviceName = string.Empty;
            foreach (var serviceAux in services)
            {
                if (string.Equals(serviceAux.ServiceId, serviceId, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                {
                    serviceName = serviceAux.Name;
                }
            }
```

La siguiente es la imagen del error que estoy presentando

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: serviceAux.Convert.ToString(ServerId)?

Comment: Convert no es una propiedad de serviceAux, recuerda que el tipo de dato se cambio de string a int

Comment: Porque si el dato **serviceId** tiene que ser `int`, lo estás comparando con un `string.Equals`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El metodo `Equals()` solo aplica a string si es que aplicas el metodo de este tipo de dato, si quiere saber si dos numeros son iguales usas el `==`

```
if (serviceAux.ServiceId == serviceId)
{
   serviceName = serviceAux.Name;
}
```

se compara directo

O sino deberias usar

[Int32.Equals Method](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.equals?view=netframework-4.8)